# Whats the difference between information_schema.user_privileges and mysql.user?

Tags: mysql, information-schema

I have the notion that privileges set in mysql.user should reflect in information_schema.user_privileges but when I try to alter some privileges in mysql.user and queried information_schema.user_privileges they did not match? Am i understanding it wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The table `mysql.user` is a MyISAM table that contains maps global database privileges. These privileges are mapped into [INFORMATION_SCHEMA.USER_PRIVILEGES](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/user-privileges-table.html) when MySQL is started.

**WARNING !!!** Be careful running UPDATE commands against `mysql.user`. You could easily forget to run `FLUSH PRIVILEGES;`.

According to the [MySQL Documentation on FLUSH PRIVILEGES](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/flush.html)

> Reloads the privileges from the grant tables in the mysql database.
>
> The server caches information in memory as a result of GRANT, CREATE
>   USER, CREATE SERVER, and INSTALL PLUGIN statements. This memory is not
>   released by the corresponding REVOKE, DROP USER, DROP SERVER, and
>   UNINSTALL PLUGIN statements, so for a server that executes many
>   instances of the statements that cause caching, there will be an
>   increase in memory use. This cached memory can be freed with FLUSH
>   PRIVILEGES.

When you execute [GRANT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/grant.html) and [REVOKE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/revoke.html) commands, the following authentication tables are changed

- `mysql.user`
- `mysql.db`
- `mysql.tables_priv`
- `mysql.columns_priv`

`FLUSH TABLES;` is executed afterwards.

You really have to know the table layouts to understand how to change privileges manually.

For example, I created a user called `pam@localhost` with the following privileges

```
mysql> show grants for pam@localhost;
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Grants for pam@localhost                                                                                   |
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO 'pam'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD '*F925CA006C127B610C43AB06E16F92EF8712F90B' |
| GRANT SELECT, INSERT ON `edwards`.`pamela_tb1` TO 'pam'@'localhost'                                        |
| GRANT SELECT, INSERT ON `edwards`.`pamela_tb3` TO 'pam'@'localhost'                                        |
| GRANT SELECT, INSERT ON `edwards`.`pamela_tb2` TO 'pam'@'localhost'                                        |
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

What does `mysql.user` look like for `pam@localhost` ?

```
mysql> select * from mysql.user where user='pam' and host='localhost'\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
                  Host: localhost
                  User: pam
              Password: *F925CA006C127B610C43AB06E16F92EF8712F90B
           Select_priv: N
           Insert_priv: N
           Update_priv: N
           Delete_priv: N
           Create_priv: N
             Drop_priv: N
           Reload_priv: N
         Shutdown_priv: N
          Process_priv: N
             File_priv: N
            Grant_priv: N
       References_priv: N
            Index_priv: N
            Alter_priv: N
          Show_db_priv: N
            Super_priv: N
 Create_tmp_table_priv: N
      Lock_tables_priv: N
          Execute_priv: N
       Repl_slave_priv: N
      Repl_client_priv: N
      Create_view_priv: N
        Show_view_priv: N
   Create_routine_priv: N
    Alter_routine_priv: N
      Create_user_priv: N
            Event_priv: N
          Trigger_priv: N
Create_tablespace_priv: N
              ssl_type:
            ssl_cipher:
           x509_issuer:
          x509_subject:
         max_questions: 0
           max_updates: 0
       max_connections: 0
  max_user_connections: 0
                plugin: mysql_native_password
 authentication_string:
      password_expired: N
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

What ??? Where are the SELECT privileges ???

They are located in `mysql.tables_priv`

```
mysql> select * from mysql.tables_priv where user='pam' and host='localhost'\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
       Host: localhost
         Db: edwards
       User: pam
 Table_name: pamela_tb1
    Grantor: redwards@localhost
  Timestamp: 0000-00-00 00:00:00
 Table_priv: Select,Insert
Column_priv:
*************************** 2. row ***************************
       Host: localhost
         Db: edwards
       User: pam
 Table_name: pamela_tb2
    Grantor: redwards@localhost
  Timestamp: 0000-00-00 00:00:00
 Table_priv: Select,Insert
Column_priv:
*************************** 3. row ***************************
       Host: localhost
         Db: edwards
       User: pam
 Table_name: pamela_tb3
    Grantor: redwards@localhost
  Timestamp: 0000-00-00 00:00:00
 Table_priv: Select,Insert
Column_priv:
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

This is how mysqld expects user privileges to be organized and distributed in the grant tables.

If you update all the privileges in mysql.user for `pam@localhost` to 'Y' and run `FLUSH PRIVILEGES;`, you will elevate `pam@localhost` to a global superuser.

This is why you are better off doing [GRANT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/grant.html) and [REVOKE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/revoke.html) and trusting mysqld to get it right.

Answer (score 0):

> INFORMATION_SCHEMA provides access to database metadata, information about the MySQL server such as the name of a database or table, the data type of a column, or access privileges. Other terms that are sometimes used for this information are data dictionary and system catalog.

Source - http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/information-schema.html

You should be taking at the proper commands for modifying accounts and `flush PRIVILEGES` to reload the PRIVILEGES.

- http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/account-management-sql.html
- http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/flush.html

Answer (score 0):

The I_S USER_PRIVILEGES table provides information about global privileges. This information comes from the `mysql.user` grant table.
This is a nonstandard table. It takes its values from the `mysql.user` table.